# Vertically centering a single block of text in a div element whose height and width are not fixed

Tags: css, centering

I found many techniques about how to vertically center some text within a div, but all those techniques depend on fixed dimensions. Is it possible to achieve when the div's height and width vary as they're expressed in percentage?

Comment: You need to google some more. For example http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: `as they're expressed in percentage` It means they are already **specified explicitly**. Hence there shouldn't be any issue with those approaches if you replace those fixed length by percentage units (Just be aware of what the percentage value refers to)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's The Best Way of Centering a Div Vertically with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to add the line  `display: table-cell;` to your css for that div

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tH2cc/1121/)